# Rule Engine for hadoop

Tags: hadoop, groovy, drools, rule-engine

I am evaluating a rule engine for my project. The project will be based on hadoop. I have done some POC using DROOLS. Basically I am using DROOL on the Mapper side. Based upon that following is my observation and query.

1) a) I fired rule on 3 millions object using DROOLS(it took around 17 sec) b) I applied the same logic using if/else loop as in DRL file for 3 millions object without drools, using simple Java objects(takes around .17 sec). b is approx. 100 times faster than a. Is this normal behaviour? Is there any way to compile Rules to java bytecode/class.

2) What is the fastest Java based rule engine framework other than DROOLS. Has someone developed rule engine using plain GROOVY. Any other framework recommendation which compiles business rule to java byte code which would result in much faster rule evaluation?

3) Has someone some experience with what is the best suited DSL/Rule framework for hadoop.

Comment: Re. 2. There are plenty of examples out there of how to use Groovy to generate DRL (for example: http://www.slideshare.net/paulk_asert/groovy-rules). You could also read the following on why DRL uses MVEL instead of something such as Groovy: http://blog.athico.com/2007/05/why-mvel-scipting-language-for-jboss.html

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the Drools/Java (Q1):

You may not have set up a fair comparison. There are several ways of "firing a rule on 3 million objects", and you may not have chosen the fastest.

It is well known that you incur a considerable overhead when you run the many pattern/many object matching algorithm in a forward chaining engine. You may not need rules at all, or a simpler (more efficient) rule evaluation technique may be sufficient.

As for comparing rule engines: this is a very iffy subject. Each benchmark has its peculiar usage scenario, and some vendors have optimized their engine for better performance with some famous (academic) test or other.

As for Q2, I don't know. Considering that developing a good rule engine takes a lot of savvy, time and effort, I doubt it very much.

I don't think that you can get an answer for Q3. "Best" is never in relation to some application framework - the yardstick is number and complexity of rules im combination with number and complexity of the data.